# .NET 4.5 - Why is StreamWriter not behaving as expected with string when writing to file?

Tags: c#, .net, streamwriter, utf

Why does the follow code output a hex string which differs from the contents of the file when viewed in a hex editor?

```
Console.Write(String.Concat(TheUTF7String.Select(c => ((int)c).ToString("x2"))).Substring(0, 40));
using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter("C:\\test", true))
{
    outfile.Write(TheUTF7String);
}
```

**Console Output**

1f8b0800000000000003c57d6b931cc5b1e867eb

**File Contents (First 32 Bytes) When Viewed In A Hex Editor**

1F C2 8B 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 C3 85 7D 6B C2 93 1C C3 85 C2 B1 C3 A8 67 C3 AB 57 34 C3 A3 C2

**To Address Phoog's Answer:**

No, it doesn't look like one character from TheUTF7String is being outputed as more than 2 hex characters:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    Console.Write(TheUTF7String.Select(c => ((int)c).ToString("x2")).ToArray()[i] + " ");
```

Outputs:
1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 c5 7d 6b 93 1c c5 b1 e8 67 eb

Comment: Can you post the string?

Comment: Not really, it is binary data: "▼      ♥Å}k?∟Å±ègë"

Comment: .NET does not have UTF-7 strings. They're all UTF-16. You need to set the encoding of the StreamWriter if you want the file to be UTF-7.

Comment: The string was created with Encoding.UTF7.GetString(buffer, 0, size)

Comment: And if I specify Encoding.UTF7 for the 3rd parameter for the StreamWriter constructor, the file output is vastly different from the console output.

Comment: GetString reads the UTF-7 encoded data from the buffer and converts it to the in-memory string representation, which is 2-byte characters.

Comment: Because the console output is UTF-16 (ish) and the file in that case is actually UTF-7.

Comment: Well if the string is really UTF-16, can you explain why the output to the console and the file is different?

Comment: What is the file's encoding? You don't seem to have told us and you haven't shown us how the file is produced. Unless the file's encoding is UTF-16, you should expect to see a difference.

Comment: @JLRishe, The default encoding which would be UTF8, although if Encoding.UTF7 is specified the file output is very different from the console output when viewed in a hex editor.

Comment: So you're using a UTF-7 decoder to read a UTF-8 file to a string and then outputting that as UTF-16. Of course that's going to be different from what you see in a hex editor. You're changing the encoding and probably corrupting it too.

Comment: Huh? When did I say the string was created by reading a UTF-8 file?

Comment: I guess I misunderstood. So the original data is UTF-7 encoded (is that right?), and you're outputting the decoded string to a file as UTF-8, but you're (sort of) writing the UTF-16 hex values to the console. Do you not see why they would be different?

Comment: The reason the values are not being output as two hex characters is that if a character's code is between 16 and 256, then `.ToString("x2")` will only produce 2 hex digits. So the values in your console are  probably not UTF-16, but rather no valid encoding scheme at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Not really, it is binary data: "▼ ♥Å}k?∟Å±ègë"

Binary data **must** be stored in a byte[].  It cannot be stored in a System.String, Unicode normalization will randomly destroy the data and your program will randomly crash when the binary data happens to match one of the surrogate values.

> Why is StreamWriter not behaving as expected

Binary data **must** be written by FileStream.  StreamWriter cannot write binary data, only text.  It will randomly destroy binary data when it encodes the string.  Utf-8 in your case, the default, producing the extra bytes.

The first quote is the most important one, this went off the rails when you assumed you could store the data in a string.  StreamWriter was the fairly inevitable next mistake.  You must use byte[] instead.  This probably means that you have to fix whatever code that obtains the data.

Answer (score 2):

The facile answer is "because your expectations are wrong."  More helpfully, I hope:

Despite the name of your string, it is a UTF-16 string ([sort of](http://blog.coverity.com/2014/04/09/why-utf-16/)).  All .NET strings are encoded this way in memory.

The default encoding for the stream writer is UTF-8, so that's what you're getting in the file.

Your buffer has the UTF-7 data.  When you call `Encoding.UTF7.GetString(buffer, 0, size)`, you get the in-memory UTF-16 representation of the same character sequence.  When you write to the StreamWriter, it calls Encoding.GetBytes to convert the string to the bytes it writes in your file.  Since it's using UTF-8 as its default encoding, you get UTF-8 data in the file.

For any values in the range 128-255 (`\u0080` to `\u00ff`), the UTF-16 character will convert to a two-digit hex code, but the UTF-8 sequence for that character will have two bytes.  This explains the difference between your console output and the hex editor.

The character `8B` is represented in UTF-8 as `C2 8B`; in UTF-16 it is `8B 00` (because the intel chip is "little endian") and when converted to int and then to a hex string, it is, of course "8B".  The UTF-7 representation seems to be `2B 41 49 73 2D`.

If you pass Encoding.Unicode to the StreamWriter, you should get the same as the console output in your hex editor, except you'll have extra `00` bytes, since `A` is represented as `41 00` in memory, but when you convert it to int and call ToString("x2"), you get "41" without the "00".

EDIT:

I just thought of another way of looking at it.  The `GetString` method *decodes* a byte sequence, returning the corresponding string, while the `GetBytes` method *encodes* a string into a corresponding byte sequence.  You can ignore the in-memory representation of the string.  (However, for your diagnostic console output, you need to keep in mind that a string is a sequence of *characters*, while a byte array is a sequence of, well, bytes.)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the case, I updated the question with a test for that.

Comment: @mattburnett ok, I'll scratch that paragraph.  More detail in a minute.

Comment: Ok. Also if I pass Encoding.UTF7 to the StreamWriter the file output is very different from the console hex output

Comment: @mattburnett that's because the console output isn't in UTF-7, but the file in that case would be in UTF-7

Comment: Anyways thanks for the insight, I think may be a little bit tired since I obviously am just not understanding this and I really should, I'll revisit this in the morning and probably select you as the answer then.

Comment: @mattburnett sleep well.  One more point: if you can discuss the bigger problem you're trying to solve -- i.e., why do you need to save the string to a file, and does it really need to be in UTF-7 format in that file -- it might lead to a more helpful answer.